Oracle redo and log_buffer
I am trying to speed up a batch process. The issue is at the code level which keeps committing a few hundred times per second, for each record processed, though it should ideally commit after process ing a batch of x records. Since it is not possible to modify the code, I am looking at other options to speed up the process. Since each transaction is only a couple of KBs at most, and no other processes access the database, will reducing the log_buffer to a size like 2 MB from the existing value (28 MB, set automatically) speed up the process? When there a commit is issued, does the logwriter write the entire log buffer or only a small portion? Answer to that question will actually decide if I should try reducing the log_buffer. If a transaction that is a few KBs results in flushing a few MBs, that is a lot of unnecessary disk I/O, right?

The log writer (LGWR) flushes redo logs from the buffer under specific conditions, such as:
A commit or rollback is issued.
The buffer becomes one-third full or reaches a threshold size.
A database checkpoint occurs.
Which means in your case since you are committing, it should write everything.
